# How do I train an SVM with scikit in python?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I have the following dataframe:

```
         A   B
40      25  95
40      25  171
40      25  109
...
```

I would like to run an svm classifier over this. I would like to predict `A` given `B`. Here's what I've done:

I create the train/test sets with:

```
a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(df.A,df.B, test_size=0.33)
```

to then (try) to train the SVM, like this:

```
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
y_pred = classifier.fit(a_train, b_train).predict(b_test)
```

And I get the following error.

```
ValueError: X and y have incompatible shapes.
X has 1 samples, but y has 27766.
```

Can anyone help me debug what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feature vector df.A is one-dimensional, but scikit always expects a 2d matrix for X. Try with reshaped matrix:

```
a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(df.A.reshape(-1,1),df.B, test_size=0.33)
```